# using layouts in qwidget

Tags: linux, qt

I am using qt 4.7 on RHEL 6.0. I am finding very difficut use te layouts.  Here is my code.

I have two widgets that are arranged using grid layout.

```
QWidget *topWidget = new QWidget();
QWidget *bottomwidget = new QWidget();
```

These two widgets are contained in a QFrame. So now i wanted to add a QPhonon::VideoPlayer widget exactly in b/w the above two widget. For adding am doing like this..

```
VideoPlayer *vPlayer = new VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory,this);
vPlayer->setSizePolicy(QSizeHint::Expanding, QSizeHint::Expanding);
QVBoxLayOut *layOut = (QVBoxLayOut*)ui->frame->layout();
layout->insertWidget(1,vPlayer,5,Qt::AlignCenter);
```

the size of all topWidget, boottomWidget are 768 and 576 which is the size of the D1 video frame. I am playing a video in vPlayer phonon widget. But what I am seeing is vPlayer size is very small and video size also small. Means to say I am not seeing the 768/576 size video. Can somebody help me? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the definition on your video ? are you sure you are playing a video that is 576 pixels wide ?

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
QVBoxLayOut *layOut = (QVBoxLayOut*)ui->frame->layout();
```

Do not use C-style casts! Use

```
dynamic_casr<QVBoxLayout*>(ui->frame->layout())
```

2)Try to vPlayer->setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 500))

3)And as far as I know Qt, if you want to change GUI or construct complicated ones, then it is preferred to construct GUI's by itself, not with QtDesigner.